# Angularjs does not intercept token provided by nodejs server by using Facebook authentication strategy

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am new to nodejs/angularjs and working on my first simple web application. I am using Facebook authentication strategy for Passport and Node.js. After successful authentication I would like to return jwt token to the client Angular app. My server code looks like this:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
        passport.authenticate('facebook', {
            failureRedirect : '/',
            session: false
        }),
        function(req, res){
            res.set("x-access-token", req.user.JWTtoken);
            res.redirect("/#/main");
        }
    );
```

My client app is trying to to intercept the response to get the provided jwt token above.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
      return {
       'request': function(config) {
           return config;

        },

        'response': function(response) {
            console.log(response.headers('x-access-token')); 


           return response;
        }
      };
    });
```

By testing this scenario I cannot see JWT token in response header. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `config` property as you're setting the header on the server. Use `response.headers` instead;

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
      return {
       'request': function(config) {
           return config;

        },

        'response': function(response) {
           console.log(response.headers('x-access-token')); 
           return response;
        }
      };
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for your prompt answer. response.headers('x-access-token') returns null. It's not quite clear for me how the redirect on the server side works in my case. I mean I set the response header and then I redirect. How the redirect is being intercepted by client app ?